# jQuery: Target position "changes" when scrolling to position within a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I already tried to have a look at similar questions, but they all don't quite answer my question. The following code works well for scrolling $('html,body'), but it does not work when I replace it with $('#my-div').

I prepared a fiddle, if you would like to play around a little: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Suw/ - To test my problem, press the button "Two" or "Three" multiple times (or press "Two" and then "Three").

**The Code:**

**CSS**

```
#test-me{
  width:100%; 
  height:120px; 
  position: relative; 
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid silver;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="test-me">
    <h1  id="one">One</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <h1 id="two">Two</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <h1 id="three">Three</h1>
    <p>...</p>
</div>

<p>
    <button data-target="#one">One</button> 
    <button data-target="#two">Two</button>  
    <button data-target="#three">Three</button>
</p>
```

**JS**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');

    var targetPosition  = $(target).position(); 

    $('#test-me').animate({
        scrollTop : targetPosition.top
    }, 425);

});
```

As I already said, it works for:

```
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop : targetPosition.top
}, 425);
```

So, why doesn't it work for the position:relative-div? Help is very much appreciated! :) I will let everyone know, if I manage to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made me a scrollTo plugin to do that basing on another example I've found on SO some time ago.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tXGWA/1/)

```
$.fn.scrollTo = function(elem, speed) {
if (!$(elem).offset()) {
    alert("Scroll-Target not defined");
    return false;
} else if (!$(this).offset()) {
    alert("Scroll-Element not defined");
    return false;       
}
scrollto = $(this).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top + $(elem).offset().top;
$(this).animate({
    scrollTop:  scrollto
}, speed == undefined ? 500 : speed); 
return this;
};
```

Using this you won't need the data attributes.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

var idx = $(this).index();
var targetObj = $($("#test-me h1").get(idx));

$("#test-me").scrollTo(targetObj, 425);

});
```

Comment: Okay, your fiddle seems to work perfectly! I will have a closer look at it and apply your approach to my actual code. So: Thank you very much! This saves me a lot of time :) (PS: I don't want to omit the data-attribute for several reasons. But thanks for the advice.)

Comment: Anytime. I think it's easy now to alter the code using the data attributes. :)